# Import table with readtable if row is shifted in .txt file

Tags: matlab, import, delimiter, csv

I have a table that looks like this

```
x x x x x x 
x x
y y y y y y
y y
z z z z z z 
z z
```

I want to import it using `readtable` such that all the x are in one row, all the y in the next row, etc. In other words, in the .txt file the last two contents that are supposed to be in one line are shifted into the next. I think I need to change something in `DelimitedTextImportOptions` but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Would be glad if someone could help me with this, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you know for certain that every line has done this? What is the format of your data (i.e. are all columns numeric etc)?

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, I know for certain that the whole table is like this. The format of the table is integers and also text strings.

Comment: You could just `textscan` your way through it, alternating between line formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a requirement to use readtable, one option would be to transform the original file to a new format and then apply readtable to the new file.

Here are sample contents of the file `in.txt` that can be used in the example below:

```
1 2 3 abc 5 6
7 8
3 4 5 def 7 8
9 0
9 1 0 ghi 3 2
1 4
```

Here is the code:

```
% FIRST, TRANSFORM THE INPUT FILE INTO A FILE WHERE THE SPLIT LINES ARE
% COMBINED INTO SINGLE LINES

% open input and output files
in = fopen('in.txt', 'r');
out = fopen('out.txt', 'w');

% read the first line of the input file
currline = fgetl(in);

% while we haven't reached the end of the file
while ~isequal(currline, -1)

    % read the following line of the input file
    currline_append = fgetl(in);
    % ... if it doesn't exist, throw an error; the file is not as expected
    if isequal(currline_append, -1)
        error('Bad file');
    end

    % print this pair of lines to the output file as a single line.
    % Note: if using Windows Notepad or similar application to read the
    % file, you may want to replace '\n' by '\r\n' in the format string
    fprintf(out, '%s %s\n', currline, currline_append);

    % get the next line of the input file
    currline = fgetl(in);
end

% close input and output files
fclose(in);
fclose(out);

% NEXT, READ THE TABLE FROM THE OUTPUT FILE

t = readtable('out.txt');
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using your version now, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if your text file is shaped **EXACTLY** and **STRICTLY** as you described (every row has the same number of elements, and two of them overflow into the next line), you can read it very easily as follows:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
data = textscan(fid,'%d','CollectOutput',true);
fclose(fid);

data_inner = data{1,1};
cols = 8; % predefined number of elements per row
rows = numel(data_inner) / cols;

C = reshape(data_inner.',cols,rows).';
```

Example of input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8
2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9
3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10
```

Example of output:

```
C =
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

Once this is done, the matrix can be easily converted into a table as follows:

```
T = array2table(C)

T =

    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8
    __    __    __    __    __    __    __    __

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7      8
    2     3     4     5     6     7     8      9
    3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10
```